# How to do running math with iterate function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, math, loops

id like to know how I can execute this.

say i have an array of values
    [0] 123
    [1] 23242
    [2] 123123
    [3] 134234
    [4] 0
    [5] 12312
    [6] 1232
    [7] 0
    [8] 2342
    [9] 0

How can i loop through this array and everytime it hits a zero, push into a new array, the sum of the preceeding values up to the last 0

eg....
my new array would contain.
    [0]  sum of first array keys [0-4]
    [1] sum of [5-7]
    [2] sum of [8-9]

Im new to PHP and cant wrap my head around how I would do this.
Like how can I look at previous values while looking through an array

thanks if anyone can help
I appreciate it

UPDATE:
So Joe wanted me to update this so he could help me further, so here it is...

I want to loop through and array, have the iterator do the math to find the sums between the zeros, and store in a new array, the value, and a running total. And then I want to be able to merge it back into the original array....eg
How do I do the running total along with the new array.

```
       Loop array        New Array, with comma delimitted values or maybe a MDA
       [0]5              [0]9,9  (sum of values in loop array between the zeros)
       [1]4              [1]7,16
       [2]0              [2]4,20 
       [3]3              [3]5,25
       [4]2 
       [5]2
       [6]0
       [7]4
       [8]0
       [9]3
       [10]2
       [11]0
```

And finally, the most important,
How do I merge it back so it will look like the following

```
       [0]5             
       [1]4             
       [2]0,9,9            
       [3]3              
       [4]2 
       [5]2
       [6]0,7,16
       [7]4
       [8]0,4,20
       [9]3
       [10]2
       [11]0,5,25
```

Thank you if you can help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$total = 0; // running total
$totals = array(); // saved totals

foreach ($values AS $value) // loop over the values
{
    $total += $value; // add to the running total
    if ($value == 0) // if it's a zero
    {
        $totals[] = $total; // save the total...
        $total = 0; // ...and reset it
    }
}
```

---

For making the first array in your update, something like this:

```
$total = 0; // running total - this will get zeroed
$grand_total = 0; // running total - this won't be zeroed
$totals = array(); // saved totals

foreach ($values AS $value) // loop over the values
{
    $total += $value; // add to the running total
    $grand_total += $value; // add it to the grand total
    if ($value == 0) // if it's a zero
    {
        $totals[] = $total . ',' . $grand_total; // save the total and the grand_total
        $total = 0; // ...and reset the zeroable total
    }
}
```

---

And for your second ("ultimate" :P) example, we just bin the new array, and instead save back into the array we're looping:

```
$total = 0; // running total - this will get zeroed
$grand_total = 0; // running total - this won't be zeroed

foreach ($values AS $key => $value) // loop over the values - $key here is the index of the current array element
{
    $total += $value; // add to the running total
    $grand_total += $value; // add it to the grand total
    if ($value == 0) // if it's a zero
    {
        $values[$key] = '0,' . $total . ',' . $grand_total; // build the new value for this element
        $total = 0; // ...and reset the zeroable total
    }
}
```

Not tested at all, but I think the logic of it should be pretty much there.

Comment: Thank you, that works, but I just realized that what I need to do is actually different.....I need to loop through the array with the values and 0's and then have the sum be added from another array.  So Im actually using 2 arrays.  One to tell me when to count and reset and the other providing the actual values to add....if you get what I mean

Comment: Update your first post with an example of each array, and how they need to combine, and then comment back on here and I'll have a look :)

Answer (score 2):

That's a basic algorithmic task...

```
$array = array( 1,3,7,9,10,0,5,7,23,3,0,6);
$result = array();

$sum = 0;
for( $i=0,$c=count($array);$i<$c;$i++ ){
    if( $array[$i]==0 ){
        $result[] = $sum;
        $sum = 0;
    }else{
        $sum += $array[$i];
    }
}

print_r($array);
```